# How to change bool of specific item in Firebase - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database called `People` and it has a child bool called `Joined` (That has a default value of false) I want to change the bool of the `People['Joined']` but just of a specific item in the database because the code `People['Joined']` changes all the `People's` Joined value to true. The code I want in words to understand better: `reference People then reference the specific key and change that key's Joined to true` (The key if automatically given to each item in the Database). The code:

```
void savebool() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setBool("People['Joined']", People['Joined']);
                //set the bool which I changed in onPressed (see below)
                //This code is not correct because It's saving every People['Joined']
    }

onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
              setState(() {
                //change specific item->key->bool
              });
              savebool();
            },
```

Extra Code that I'm not sure is useful:

```
Query dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('People');

Expanded(
          child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
            query: dbRef,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                Animation<double> animation, int index) {
              Map People = snapshot.value as Map;
              //
              if (People['Date'] ==
                  DateFormat("d-MM-yyyy").format(_selectedDate)) {
                return listItem(People: People);
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            },
          ),
```

Database:

[image: My Firebase Realtime Database for better understanding]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update it like below

```
 _updateValue() async {
        await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref()
.child('People').child('peopleId').update({'Joined':true});
    }
```